# Laravel View contains additional '<' character

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel view page displays  additional '<' character,but it is not given in the code. How can I fix it? I have given the blade.php code for the view. While inspecting, all the tags are misplaced and the head tag is shown inside the body tag.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            @if (Route::has('login'))
                <div class="top-right links">
                    @auth
                        <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>

                        @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                        @endif
                    @endauth
                </div>
            @endif

            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    Laravel
                </div>

                <div class="links">
                    <a href="https://laravel.com/docs">Docs</a>
                    <a href="https://laracasts.com">Laracasts</a>
                    <a href="https://laravel-news.com">News</a>
                    <a href="https://blog.laravel.com">Blog</a>
                    <a href="https://nova.laravel.com">Nova</a>
                    <a href="https://forge.laravel.com">Forge</a>
                   <a href="https://github.com/laravel/laravel">GitHub</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Search for << on the login page.

Comment: extra `<` somewhere in html tag start.

Comment: Right click and Inspect it in Dev tools.

Comment: can you post your blade files ?

Comment: The extra `<` can also be located in one of your `.php` file e.g.: `<<?php`

Comment: The problem was with the route file in laravel(routes/web.php),an extra '<' were added accidently and finally the problem was fixed.